# Is there any logic coding for date with condition continuous and not continuous day?

Tags: jsp

There is condition where student are absent for 3 days continuously and 7 day not continuously will be given first warning letter

```
if totalstatuskehadiran >3{ 

else
}
return;
```

Comment: more info is needed. Are there any java beans involved? Show some code: jsp, javabean, model, datastructure,..

Comment: I have fixed your code block, but I still don't understand what you are asking. Please [edit] your question and add some context.

Comment: i've no idea how to create the logic coding for this condition..here i want to use if else statement for alerting user with email when the total of statuskehadiran = absent for 3 days continuously or 7 days uncontinuously..then 1st warning letter will be email to certain user

Comment: i don't know how to make the condition for 3 days continuous and uncontinuous..this condition according to date